# select isn't populating from JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I'm having trouble with the following code.

The JSON data seems to be generated properly and the select field is being emptied of existing options as I expect it should, however, the options generated from the JSON data are not being appended to the select.

I'm not getting a console error and I am not seeing what why it's not appending.

Any suggestions?

```
<script>
$('#campReg').change(function() {

var $self = $(this);
$.ajax ({
url: 'php/getCamps.php', 
data: { id : $self.val()},
dataType:'JSON',
type:'POST',

    success: function(data){
            var sel = $('#otherCamps').empty();

            var toAppend = '';
            $.each(data,function(i,data){

                toAppend += '<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.desc+'</option>';
            });
        $('#sessions').append(toAppend);
    }
    })
});
</script>
```

The JSON:

```
{data: [{id:1, desc:06/09 - 06/13 - WEATHER}, {id:3, desc:08/01 - 08/04 - TEST CAMP}]}
```

Comment: What is your HTML markup?

Comment: <select id="otherCamps" name="otherCamps" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option>temp data</option>
    </select>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/draditya91/9uTwu/1):

Make these two changes to your code:

```
$.each(data.data,function(i,data){
```

and

```
$('#otherCamps').append(toAppend);
```

**So your code will be:**

```
$('#campReg').change(function() {
var $self = $(this);
$.ajax ({
url: 'php/getCamps.php', 
data: { id : $self.val()},
dataType:'JSON',
type:'POST',

    success: function(data){
            $('#otherCamps').empty();

            var toAppend = '';
            $.each(data.data,function(i,data){

                toAppend += '<option value="'+data.id+'">'+data.desc+'</option>';
            });
        $('#otherCamps').append(toAppend);
    }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `success: function(data)` receives the whole json object in data, but it has a data property that holds the actual array. So you have to iterate over data.data: `$.each(data.data, ...`

Comment: changed to my code to $.each(data.data,function(i,data)

Still doesn't work. I get the same result, nothing in the target select.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you need to use:

```
$('#otherCamps').append(toAppend);
```

instead of:

```
$('#sessions').append(toAppend);
```

since you've assigned `id="otherCamps"` to your `select` element.